# Open popup once the page is load using href

Tags: jquery, popup

How can I show the popup on page load using href? what I did is to show the popup using `href`

`<a class="btn btn-primary skip popop-btn" href="#popup1">OPEN POPUP</a>` if I clicked this link it will show my popup. What I want is to automatically show popup on page load without clicking it?

This is my code for simple jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      //My function for showing the popup
   },3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

step1: set id for the a tag
step2: trigger the click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#linkId").trigger("click");
   },3000);
});
```